# How to set nodeSelector for controller for AWS EKS aws-ebs-csi-addon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I have the problem, that when I want to set a nodeSelector for the ebs-csi-controller, that it runs in a problem.

The problem message:

```
UnsupportedAddonModification: Amazon EKS was unable to complete the addon operation. The configuration values provided are invalid.
```

Before I started I run the describe-addon command, to get the information which properties can be set. There is a property where I can set the nodeSelector for the controller.

```
{
    "$defs": {
        "extraVolumeTags": {
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    "maxLength": 256,
                    "minLength": 0,
                    "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9 _\\.:\\/=+\\-@]*$",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "propertyNames": {
                "maxLength": 128,
                "minLength": 1,
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9 _\\.:\\/=+\\-@]*$",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "description": "Configurable parameters of the AWS EBS CSI Driver",
    "properties": {
        "a1CompatibilityDaemonSet": {
            "default": false,
            "description": "Enable compatibility for the A1 instance family via use of an AL2-based image in a separate DaemonSet",
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "additionalDaemonSets": {
            "default": {},
            "description": "Additional DaemonSets of the node pod",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    "$ref": "#/properties/node",
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "controller": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "additionalArgs": {
                    "default": [],
                    "description": "Additional arguments passed to the controller pod",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "affinity": {
                    "default": {
                        "affinity": {
                            "nodeAffinity": {
                                "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
                                    {
                                        "preference": {
                                            "matchExpressions": [
                                                {
                                                    "key": "eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type",
                                                    "operator": "NotIn",
                                                    "values": [
                                                        "fargate"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "weight": 1
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "podAntiAffinity": {
                                "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
                                    {
                                        "podAffinityTerm": {
                                            "labelSelector": {
                                                "matchExpressions": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "app",
                                                        "operator": "In",
                                                        "values": [
                                                            "ebs-csi-controller"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname"
                                        },
                                        "weight": 100
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "Affinity of the controller pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "batching": {
                    "default": true,
                    "description": "Enable batching of API calls. Improves performance in workloads that are sensitive to EC2 rate limits.",
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "extraVolumeTags": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/extraVolumeTags",
                    "default": {},
                    "description": "Additional tags to be added to all EBS volumes"
                },
                "loggingFormat": {
                    "default": "text",
                    "description": "Log format for the driver container on the controller pod",
                    "enum": [
                        "text",
                        "json"
                    ],
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nodeSelector": {
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Node selector of the controller pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "podAnnotations": {
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Annotations applied to the controller pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "resources": {
                    "default": {
                        "limits": {
                            "memory": "256Mi"
                        },
                        "requests": {
                            "cpu": "10m",
                            "memory": "40Mi"
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "Resource requests/limits of the controller pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "sdkDebugLog": {
                    "default": false,
                    "description": "Enables debug logging of the AWS SDK via --aws-sdk-debug-log=true",
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "serviceAccount": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "annotations": {
                            "default": null,
                            "description": "Additional annotations added to the ebs-csi-controller-sa service account",
                            "type": [
                                "object",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "tolerations": {
                    "default": [
                        {
                            "key": "CriticalAddonsOnly",
                            "operator": "Exists"
                        },
                        {
                            "effect": "NoExecute",
                            "operator": "Exists",
                            "tolerationSeconds": 300
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": "Tolerations of the controller pod",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "volumeModificationFeature": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "enabled": {
                            "default": false,
                            "description": "Enable modification of volume type, iops, etc via volume-modifier-for-k8s sidecar",
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "customLabels": {
            "default": null,
            "description": "Custom labels added to Kubernetes objects",
            "type": [
                "object",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "node": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "additionalArgs": {
                    "default": [],
                    "description": "Additional arguments passed to the node pod",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "affinity": {
                    "default": {
                        "nodeAffinity": {
                            "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
                                "nodeSelectorTerms": [
                                    {
                                        "matchExpressions": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type",
                                                "operator": "NotIn",
                                                "values": [
                                                    "fargate"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "Affinity of the node pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "kubeletPath": {
                    "default": "/var/lib/kubelet",
                    "description": "Kubelet path of the node",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "loggingFormat": {
                    "default": "text",
                    "description": "Log format for the driver container on the node pod",
                    "enum": [
                        "text",
                        "json"
                    ],
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nodeSelector": {
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Node selector of the node pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "podAnnotations": {
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Annotations applied to the node pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "resources": {
                    "default": {
                        "limits": {
                            "memory": "256Mi"
                        },
                        "requests": {
                            "cpu": "10m",
                            "memory": "40Mi"
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "Resource requests/limits of the node pod",
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "serviceAccount": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "annotations": {
                            "default": null,
                            "description": "Additional annotations added to the ebs-csi-node-sa service account",
                            "type": [
                                "object",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "tolerateAllTaints": {
                    "default": true,
                    "description": "Node pods will tolerate all taints",
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "tolerations": {
                    "default": [
                        {
                            "effect": "NoExecute",
                            "operator": "Exists",
                            "tolerationSeconds": 300
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": "Tolerations of the node pod",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "volumeAttachLimit": {
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Overrides the maximum number of volumes that can be attached per node (for all nodes)",
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "type": [
                        "integer",
                        "null"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "proxy": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "http_proxy": {
                    "default": "",
                    "description": "Value of HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "no_proxy": {
                    "default": "",
                    "description": "Value of NO_PROXY environment variable",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "sidecars": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "attacher": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the attacher container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "livenessProbe": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the livenessprobe container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "nodeDriverRegistrar": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the node-driver-registrar container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "provisioner": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the provisioner container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "resizer": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the resizer container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "snapshotter": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the snapshotter container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        },
                        "forceEnable": {
                            "default": true,
                            "description": "Enables/disables the external-snapshotter sidecar",
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "volumemodifier": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "additionalArgs": {
                            "default": [],
                            "description": "Additional arguments passed to the volumemodifier container",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

With this information I build my addon-update.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: eks-dev-cluster
  region: eu-central-1

addons:
- name: aws-ebs-csi-driver
  version: v1.28.0-eksbuild.1
  serviceAccountRoleARN: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole
  configurationValues: |-
    controller:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
        monitoring: 'true'
  resolveConflicts: overwrite
```

When I try to update the addon with following command, `eksctl update addon -f addon-update.yaml --profile My-Profile`, I get the error message `UnsupportedAddonModification: Amazon EKS was unable to complete the addon operation. The configuration values provided are invalid.`.

I get the same error message if I change the configurationValues to Json or if I try to update with Advanced configuration in the UI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVZkK.png)

Does anyone can say where my error is?

Thank you very much!

With best regards
Unbr8kable